# In rails 3, how to get cookies from a views helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
module MailerHelper
  def test_get_cookies
    if cookies[:country]
      " zzz #{cookies[:country]} zzz"
    end
  end
 end
```

I put this method in some layout:
     <%= test_get_cookies %>

Error:
     undefined method `cookies' for nil:NilClass

Comment: You should be able to get `cookies` from the helper - what happens when you invoke `cookies` in the view directly?

Answer (score 0):

pass the relevant country cookie to that function .

module MailerHelper
  def test_get_cookies(country_val)
    if country_val
      " zzz #{cookies[:country]} zzz"
    end
  end
 end